# Mentioned incorrect high-schools names during interview, should I contact and clarify?

Tags: interviewing, job-search, resume

So I had a job interview and we had some casual conversation, especially since I have family in the area.

I was homeschooled through high school, but took some classes at local schools to supplement that, and I mentioned that in the interview. Unfortunately, I accidentally mentioned the wrong school, and didn't realize that until the interview was over.

These extra classes were not listed on my resume. It was such a long time ago (well over a decade) that the exact answer slipped my mind. Not to mention that I have really bad anxiety about interviews and was running on very little sleep.

Do you think I'm worrying over nothing, or should I contact them to correct it? I'm inclined to think it doesn't matter because it was so long ago, but I'd like a second opinion.

Comment: Minor clarification: you mention "took some classes at local schools", but then say "I mentioned the wrong school"... which one is it? were you in several or just one?

Comment: No, don't contact them. No one cares.

Comment: There were two different schools where I took extra classes, but I mixed one of them up with the school that other people I knew went to in a different district than mine. I didn't mention the other one at all.

Comment: I did it because it was in the same county/general area that I grew up in during my high school years, and the culture there is the sort where people tend to bring up places they're familiar with in . Like 'oh, are you familiar with X place?' 'Of course, I went to classes there!' That's just the way everyone talks (including me).

Comment: Do nothing at present. If they invite you back for a second, normally final interview, you can always pass it off as nerves at the end and just hand over a sheet listing the extra modules you did at the accurately named school.

If you do not get invited back, ringing them will be pointless since there will be something far more major that caused them to appoint better qualified applicants.

Why not re-write your CV/resume to include the extra modules you did at a state school to beef up your pre-college education. I admit, I would have an antipathy to anyone who was home schooled.

Comment: @Nikki you say you have antipathy to anyone who was homeschooled. Are you for real?

Answer (score 8):

> Unfortunately, I accidentally mentioned the wrong school, and didn't realize that until the interview was over. These extra classes were not listed on my resume.

You say this was 10+ years ago, pertaining high-school, and that you didn't list those on your resume (so you just casually mentioned it during the interview).

You mentioned you were stressed and without much sleep. Not to put in doubt your word, but it's also likely that you did mention the correct name and are just having an illusion (due to the stress and few sleep).

Summing all that up, I would say that this is something not worth biting your nails off for.

I'd also suggest that you keep applying as to keep your options open, until you get an offer and a contract. Good luck with the job-search.

Comment: Actually the school mentioned was wrong because I mixed it up with the school where some people I knew went, and my lack of sleep made me mix up the names.

Answer (score 4):

If you are a college grad, nobody cares about your high school unless there was something exceptional about it or about what you did while there.

Comment: Even if the author only has a high school diploma, I am not sure anyone would care if it was over a decade ago. Any reason for hiring the author would come down to either a personal reason for the hiring authority (i.e., gut-based or other) or based on what is presumably 10 years of experience in their field.

Answer (score 2):

I would think the discussion you were having was the small talk part of the interview.

While every interaction you have with them is part of the interview process, the discussion you were having is unlikely to have a known answer.  Contacting them to correct a statement you might have made alerts them to the fact that you struggle with small talk, and that you constantly worry about minor things.

I guess that you could have butchered the school name so bad, that it looked like you had no idea what you were talking about. I don't know if contacting them to correct the record will help the situation.

I would not discuss it with them. But I would find some other reason to reach out to them if they don't contact you in a reasonable amount of time.